# Error in the following Function?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want the following JS to hide the modal when POST is successful. Why does it not work? I am new to JS. Thanks a lot.

```
dpd.posts.post({
    name: name,
}, function(posts, error) {
    if (error) {
        return showError(error)
    } else {
        $('#modal').modal('hide');
    }
    addYourposts(yourposts);
    $('#name').val('');
});

return false;

});
```

Comment: We have no clue why it does not work. What is the error? What is the problem? What does not work?

Comment: @epascarello  It won't hide the modal.  The error message works, but the modal won't hide.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$(element).hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

```
$('#modal').hide()
```

If you are using a jQuery extension for displaying the modal. The modal may have its own API/syntax for closing the modal correctly. e.g 1 `$('#modal').modal('hide')`

If your getting a error then provide it please